# Unix Script Replace String in multiple files and do save under another name

Tags: unix, batch-file, sed, replace

I am trying to build a script that use "sed" to do the following :

- Search for files ending with .config  (ie: test.js.config) in the current directory and all under it.
- Replace a string with another one (ie: {TEST} -> 50)
- Save the result in a new file that does not have the .config at the end (ex: test.js)
- Delete the original .config file (ie: test.js.config)

It would be great if it would be able to use another file that has the "string to search" with a "string to replace", like a dictionnary :

> {TEST} = 50
>
> {FIRST_NAME} = Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a bunch of sed `s///` commands in a file:

```
$ cat change.sed 
s/{TEST}/50/g
s/{FIRST_NAME}/Alex/g
```

If you have the following config input:
    $ cat test.js.config 
    alert({TEST})
    alert({FIRST_NAME})

The result will be:

```
$ sed -f change.sed test.js.config > test.js
$ cat test.js
alert(50)
alert(Alex)
```

The syntax is not great, but it is neither horrendous :)

OTOH, if you really want to use the bracket syntax in the replacing file...

```
$ cat test.js.config 
alert({TEST})
alert({FIRST_NAME})
```

... and the key-value pair in the replacement file...

```
$ cat change.txt 
TEST=50
FIRST_NAME=Alex
```

...you can write a sed command to change the key-value pair in sed replacements...

```
$ sed 's#\(.*\)=\(.*\)#s/{\1}/\2/g#' change.txt
s/{TEST}/50/g
s/{FIRST_NAME}/Alex/g
```

...and use this command in the real replacement:

```
$ sed "$(sed 's#\(.*\)=\(.*\)#s/{\1}/\2/g#' change.txt)" test.js.config > test.js
$ cat test.js
alert(50)
alert(Alex)
```

Comment: Is there anyway I can make the shell script figures out the original name and the new name by itself? I mean, to detect the name WITH and WITHOUT the .config extension, without having to manually input every filename I wish to convert? Also, if possible, to delete the .config file at the end.

Comment: @Frederic: if name is "foo.config", then `${name%.config}` is "foo".  Try: `ls | grep \.config$ | while read name; do echo $name ${name%.config}; done`

Comment: @FredericHutow of course! `for f in *.config; do sed "$(sed 's#\(.*\)=\(.*\)#s/{\1}/\2/g#' change.txt)" $f > ${f/.config/} && rm $f
done`

Comment: @FredericHutow: If you want to descend into subdirectories, you can  `find . | grep '.config$' | while read f; do ...`